# Keeping Eclipse project dependencies in sync with an external build system

Tags: eclipse, build, gradle

Here is the situation. A development team has a large number (hundreds) of Eclipse projects. The code is very much in churn - new projects are being created; projects are being renamed and project dependencies are constantly changing. The external build system is ant. It is proving extremely challenging to keep the dependencies defined in the ant build files in sync with the state of the world in Eclipse. The external ant build needs constant changes to keep up. For various reasons, using ant as the default builder in Eclipse is not an option. The developers want to continue using Eclipse as the build and edit environment for local use.

Question: Is there a tool which will allow a single set of dependencies to be maintained which can be used by Eclipse as well as an external build system like ant? 
I have heard of Gradle but never used it before. Would it make sense in this context? I am pretty sure Maven wouldnt work for what is needed
The typical workflow should be: 
1. Developers continue working as they currently do - creating and changing Eclipse project dependencies at will and using the default Eclipse builder to compile and test locally.
2. Some mechanism exists by which these dependencies can be carried into an external build system like ant  and an external continuous build triggered on every checkin.
Appreciate your feedback - thanks!

Comment: Why would maven not work? In relationship with M2E (currently in Indigo) this exactly works ...If you would like to use a build system like Maven, Gradle or Ant then the changes to confguration/dependencies etc. have to be done in the build system and NOT in Eclipse...The leading system is the build system and not the IDE...The dev have to learn that Eclipse is NOT a build system it's just an working environment but not intended to be an Build System.

Comment: Thanks for the M2E reference - I will take a look. The main reason for not making the switch-over to the build system being the leading systemm is historical - an external build system did not exist when work began and was only recently introduced. It would be nice to integrate it unobtrusively into the workflow dev is already used to. Assuming one does bite the bullet and make the build system the leading system, is there an automated way of sucking out existing Eclipse project dependencies into Maven/Gradle or even Ant?

Answer (score 2):

We have been quite successful at using Gradle to tackle a similar problem. Here's the outline of the setup

- Each project contains a `build.gradle` that defines project specific dependencies and tasks (may even be empty).
- A special `master` project contains `build.gradle` that sets up common dependencies and tasks for child projects, and/or injects settings pertinent to a group of child projects.

  - Logically `master` project is the *parent* project, but it exists as a sibling folder so that Eclipse can be more comfortable with it.
- Gradle contains a built-in Eclipse plugin which allows generation of Eclipse settings files for each of the projects from the dependencies information (including inter-project dependencies).  It works nicely for simple projects, and as for more complicated ones Gradle allows you to tinker with the settings files, so you can do pretty much everything. From here you have two options:

  - Not to store Eclipse settings file in the repository and call the generation task every time you do a fresh check-out (I prefer this option).
  - Tell Gradle to use custom variables to make it generate generic settings files which can be checked-in to the repository. You'll then only need to run the generation task when dependencies or other configuration changes.
- (Optional) It's a little tricky, but you can make Gradle parse existing project `ivy.xml` files and set up dependencies from there. I had some success with this, although I would recommend converting dependencies into Gradle format for more flexibility.
- Continuous build system integrate with Gradle very well (same as ant). If you are using Jenkins (Hudson) there is a Gradle plugin.

The advantage of using Gradle is that it scales pretty well, and you can support other IDEs like IntelliJ or Netbeans at the same time without much effort (unless you have lots of crazy custom settings). An advantage and a disadvantage is that Gradle is a powerful build system which requires learning Groovy and Gradle DSL which may take some time to acquire. Also the documentation is awesome.

Gradle has a very active community with the sole purpose of tackling exactly this kind of problem.

Hope this helps, and best of luck!

Comment: Thanks @rodion - decided to give grails a whirl. Thanks for the helpful information. I will update this topic when I finish my investigatiob

Answer (score 0):

How about parsing the .classpath files, generate a dependency tree and start building from the root. What you need is a convention on the layout of your projects or an generic (ant-) buildfile that could be changed in each project, if needed (e.g. different project layouts). I´m not sure if Eclipse Tycho could be used for that, since it´s a maven plugin(s) to build eclipse plugins or projects. But it´s able to resolve the bundle and project dependencies against maven repositories and eclipse update sites.